# Good pedagogical ressources on suffix arrays

Tags: suffix-array

I simply cannot find any good pedagogical ressource explaining suffix arrays. Even the ["bible"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) doesn't cover it.

Where can I find a clear and thorough explanation of suffix arrays and their uses? (A video course would be ideal, because I'm lazy.)

Comment: Programming Pearls 
- http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s15.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prof Dan Gusfield gave a lecture on this topic : http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/cs222f07/lineartimesuffixarray.wmv . You might find it useful

Comment: That's a great video indeed. +1 for this. It should be said though that this is basically a (very good and instructive) explanation of the Skew algorithm, i.e. one particular algorithm for the _construction_ of suffix arrays. But since there are many videos on other topics on the [main page](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/cs222f07/videolist.html), perhaps he'll add videos on other aspects, too. It would be great, for sure.

Comment: Thanks Kakira. Do you know which video is the continuation of this one, where he discusses *applications* of suffix arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Many a thing you can do with a suffix array has in the past been described on the basis of the *suffix tree*. A great text book covering that is the [*Algorithms* book](http://www.librarything.com/work/84022) by Dan Gusfield.

A great resource when it comes to suffix array search, representation and compression is the survey paper by Navarro and Mäkinen [DOI 10.1145/1216370.1216372](http://scholar.google.co.jp/scholar?cluster=9064982197003274356&hl=ja&as_sdt=0,5).

Comment: Worth noting is that the video posted above is Dan Gusfield.